# Running Django unittests with postgresql 9.3, is this even possible?

Tags: django, postgresql

Running unittests with Django 1.7 on sqlite is a no brainer.  Couple of config lines and you are good to go.  With Postgres, it almost seems impossible.

I create the test database, set the owner of the DB and the Schema to the user testing, grant all on database to testing and we should be good to go right?  BUT NO!

```
postgres=# create user testing with password '*****';
postgres=# create database project_test;
postgres=# grant all on database project_test to testing;
postgres=# alter database project_test owner to testing;
postgres=# \c project_test;
postgres=# alter schema public owner to testing;

(project) $python manage.py test
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
Got an error creating the test database: permission denied to create database

Type 'yes' if you would like to try deleting the test database 'project_test', or 'no' to cancel: yes
Destroying old test database 'default'...
Got an error recreating the test database: permission denied to create database

postgres=# grant create on tablespace pg_default to testing;
```

brings me back around to

```
Type 'yes' if you would like to try deleting the test database 'project_test', or 'no' to cancel: yes
Destroying old test database 'default'...
Got an error recreating the test database: database "project_test" does not exist
```

It seems django's desire to drop the database puts a spanner in the works.

I have a script to wipe the db and recreate the structure that looks like this

```
set -e
python manage.py dbshell <<EOF
DROP SCHEMA public CASCADE;
CREATE SCHEMA public;
EOF
```

This works just fine.  I know best practices are to test on the same engine you run in production, but everywhere I look all the testing is being done on sqlite which won't work for me because I'm now using a citext column and want to test the behavior of the code with that column type.

How do I get to the point I can test with postgres?

Comment: Since *all* the Django core developers, without exception, prefer Postgres, you can be sure that it is not only possible but recommended.

Comment: I hear, you, but even two scoops default test settings, just use sqlite, not postgres for test https://github.com/twoscoops/django-twoscoops-project/blob/develop/project_name/project_name/settings/test.py

Answer (score 1):

I have a setup like the one you are talking about in your question.

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    #'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
    'NAME': '#####',
    'USER': '#####',
    'PASSWORD': DJANGO_DB_PASSWORD
```

this uses the postgres database in testing, but, you need to remember that it only uses the schema, you cannot run unit tests using real database values.

I did have to create the database in postgres for it to work.

Not sure if this will help you.

Comment: I don't know what you meant by `you cannot run unit tests using real database values`  I know it creates the db anew each run, that's no problem, my problem is when it drops the db, it can no longer re-create the db to run the tests.  Are you not seeing this problem?  What version of Django are you running?  I'm using 1.7.5

Comment: I'm using 1.7.7, I can run tests after the teardown is done, but there are no values left after the tests are one, as these are cleared with the db, starting up a new test batch works perfectly

Comment: I upgraded to 1.7.7, but no change, can you tell me how your schema is owned?  Or are you using postgres as your db user?  My problem is that once the database is dropped, It can't be recreated.

Comment: Yes, my db user is the owner of the db and I gave it general privilages on the postgerss side to allow it to create dbs